# Animation Nodes: Simple Grid Mesh not working

Tags: animation-nodes

What's wrong with the following nodes setup? Why doesn't it create copies of Suzane?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the number of instances from the vertex list:

[image]

There is only 1 grid mesh, so it feeds just single instance.

Answer (score 1):

what version of AN are you using? 
my grid mesh looks a bit different. but it should work for you if you connect the vertices output to the instances of the object output (not the Mesh)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That was basically the mistake. And I'm using latest version of AN (2.1 I guess).